# Wanted to see if anyone has any insight to why an "ambigious use of subscript" error is created in one project vs. another in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, subscript

So based on the following project tutorial [expandableCells](http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/), using sub-scripting with NSMutableArray works. (I opened the project myself in xcode and get no errors)

When I try to utilize this workflow in my own project, I get "ambiguous use of subscript" errors all over the place. This is the same issue asked in a previous question [Ambiguous use of subscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915840/ambiguous-use-of-subscript)

My question would be why would the project provided by appcoda work in xcode but similar code not work when trying to utilize a similar workflow in a new project. Now mind you, the issue appears to be how swift is handling NSMutableArray because when I rewrite the code as a swift array and dictionary, everything works except there is no easy way to convert the plist to a swift array.

My plist is in the same format as the tutorial: Array, Array, Dictionary

Here is a snip where I am seeing the error

```
var cellDescriptors: NSMutableArray!

func loadSections() {

    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NewCells", ofType: "plist")!
    cellDescriptors = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)
    getIndicesOfVisibleRows()
    tblExpandable.reloadData()
}

func getIndicesOfVisibleRows() {
    visibleRowsPerSection.removeAll()

    for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors {
        var visibleRows = [Int]()

        for row in 0...((currentSectionCells ).count - 1) {
**ERROR HERE==>** if currentSectionCells[row]["isVisible"] as! Bool == true {
                visibleRows.append(row)
            }
        }

        visibleRowsPerSection.append(visibleRows)

        print("visibleRows \(self.visibleRowsPerSection)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try loading it and casting as [AnyObject]. `var cellDescriptors: [AnyObject] = [ ]` `cellDescriptors  = NSArray(contentsOfURL: url) as? [AnyObject] ?? []`

Comment: It depends on many things, if applying subscript to `AnyObject` causes "Ambiguous use of subscript" or not. List up all imports in your project, and see which of them are affecting.

Comment: @leo, that didn't work. That triggered a nasty segmentation fault error. at OOPer, my only import is UIKit. Thank you everyone for your responses.

Comment: @cmarti1138 I am pretty sure my code it is not responsible for that error as you can see it has a nil coalescing operator to return an empty array. That error is coming from somewhere else in your code. BTW you still  need to deal with your array sub elements casting from AnyObject to Dictionary or something else. Try printing the cellDescriptors content after loading it from file. Just use URLForResource(withExtension:) instead of pathForResource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is explained in the answer you linked to, Foundation containers (`NSArray`,  `NSDictionary` etc) are untyped.  So, `currentSelectionCells[row]` returns `AnyObject`.  Swift won't let you subscript an `AnyObject` since it may not be a container.  It could literally be anything.

If you look closely at the code in the AppCoda article where you have

```
for row in 0...((currentSectionCells ).count - 1) {
```

they have

```
for row in 0...((currentSectionCells as! [[String: AnyObject]]).count - 1) {
```

They have bridged `currentSelectCells` to a Swift array containing a Swift dictionary of `String:AnyObject`so when they later say `currentSelectionCells[row]` they get back a dictionary `[String:AnyObject]`. This *is* subscriptable and Swift is happy.

So, there *is* an easy way to convert a plist to a Swift array.  It is generally best to convert Foundation containers to Swift containers at the earliest opportunity since then you get the advantages of member typing.  It would have been better if they had implemented `loadCellDescriptors` as something like:

```
var cellDescriptors: [[String:AnyObject]]!

func loadCellDescriptors() {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CellDescriptor", ofType: "plist") {
        let plist = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)
        cellDescriptors = plist as! [[String:AnyObject]]
        getIndicesOfVisibleRows()
        tblExpandable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I tried the last part worked, but I had to cast NSMutableArray to NSArray first before I could cast it to a swift array. As another experiment, I also tried copying the 2 classes from the appcoda file in to new files in my project as I figured that would work just as is, and the same ambiguous errors popped up. ty for all of the replies. I will mark this as the correct answer.